# GCP recommendation data format for catalog

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recommendation-engine

I am currently working on recommendation AI. since I am new to GCP recommendation, I have been struggling with data format for catalog. I read the documentation and it says each product item JSON format should be on a single line.

I understand this totally, but It would be really great if I could get what the JSON format looks like in real because the one in their documentation is very ambiguous to me. and I am trying to use console to import data

I tried to import data looking like down below but I got error saying invalid JSON format 100 times. it has lots of reasons such as unexpected token and something should be there and so on.

```
 [
    {
     "id": "1",
     "title": "Toy Story (1995)",
     "categories": [
      "Animation",
      "Children's",
      "Comedy"
     ]
    },
    {
     "id": "2",
     "title": "Jumanji (1995)",
     "categories": [
      "Adventure",
      "Children's",
      "Fantasy"
     ]
    },
...
]
```

Maybe it was because each item was not on a single line, but I am also wondering if the above is enough for importing. I am not sure if those data should be included in another property like

```
{
 "inputConfig": {
  "productInlineSource": {
   "products": [
    {
     "id": "1",
     "title": "Toy Story (1995)",
     "categories": [
      "Animation",
      "Children's",
      "Comedy"
     ]
    },
    {
     "id": "2",
     "title": "Jumanji (1995)",
     "categories": [
      "Adventure",
      "Children's",
      "Fantasy"
     ]
    },
}
```

I can see the above in the documentation but it says it is for importing inline which is using POST request. it does not mention anything about importing with console. I just guess the format is also used for console but I am not 100% sure. that is why I am asking

Is there anyone who can show me the entire data format to import data by using console?

**Problem Solved**

For those who might have the same question, The exact data format you should import by using gcp console looks like

```
{"id":"1","title":"Toy Story (1995)","categories":["Animation","Children's","Comedy"]}
{"id":"2","title":"Jumanji (1995)","categories":["Adventure","Children's","Fantasy"]}
```

1. No square bracket wrapping all the items.
2. No comma between items.
3. Only each item on a single line.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What exactly you want to achieve. You reffered to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog)? From what product you want to import catalog? Did you get any error when you try?

Comment: @PjoterS, I edited my question. I just wanna import data using console. so I just wanna see what exactly data should look like when you import data using console. that is it.

Comment: Im glad you found solution. Please post your solution as an answer. It will be more visible and might help other users with similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this `Community Wiki` for better visibility.

OP edited question and add solution:

> The exact data format you should import by using gcp console looks like

```
{"id":"1","title":"Toy Story (1995)","categories":["Animation","Children's","Comedy"]}
{"id":"2","title":"Jumanji (1995)","categories":["Adventure","Children's","Fantasy"]}
```

> - No square bracket wrapping all the items.
> - No comma between items.
> - Only each item on a single line.

However I'd like to elaborate a bit.
There are a few ways to import [Importing catalog information](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog):

- [Importing catalog data from Merchant Center](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog#mc)
- [Importing catalog data from BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog#bq)
- [Importing catalog data from Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog#json)

I guess this is what was used by OP, as I was able to import catalog using UI and GCS with below `JSON` file.

```
{
"inputConfig": {
"catalogInlineSource": {
  "catalogItems": [
    {"id":"111","title":"Toy Story (1995)","categories":["Animation","Children's","Comedy"]}
    {"id":"222","title":"Jumanji (1995)","categories":["Adventure","Children's","Fantasy"]}
    {"id":"333","title":"Test Movie (2020)","categories":["Adventure","Children's","Fantasy"]}
  ]
}
}
}
```

- [Importing catalog data inline](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog#inline)

At the bottom of the [Importing catalog information](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/upload-catalog#json-format) documentation you can find information:

> The line breaks are for readability; you should **provide an entire catalog item on a single line. Each catalog item should be on its own line.**

It means you should use something similar to [NDJSON](https://clue.engineering/2018/introducing-reactphp-ndjson) - convenient format for storing or streaming structured data that may be processed one record at a time.

If you would like to try `inline method`, you should use this format, however it's single line but with breaks for readability.

***data.json*** file

```
{
"inputConfig": {
"catalogInlineSource": {
  "catalogItems": [
    {
      "id": "1212",
      "category_hierarchies": [ { "categories": [ "Animation", "Children's" ]  } ],
      "title": "Toy Story (1995)"
    },
    {
      "id": "5858",
      "category_hierarchies": [ { "categories": [ "Adventure", "Fantasy" ]  } ],
      "title": "Jumanji (1995)"
    },
    {
      "id": "321123",
      "category_hierarchies": [ { "categories": [ "Comedy", "Adventure" ]  } ],
      "title": "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)"
    },
  ]
}
}
}
```

***Command***

```
curl -X POST \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
 --data @./data.json \
"https://recommendationengine.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[your-project]/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/catalogItems:import"
{
  "name": "import-catalog-default_catalog-1179023525XX37366024",
  "done": true
}
```

Please keep in mind that the above method requires [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#manually) authentication, otherwise you will get `PERMISSION DENIED` error.

```
  "message" : "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the translate.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
```